# How to find specific values in a pandas dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe has a column for name, group, and a few other values. It looks something like this, for reference

| Name | Group |
| --- | --- |
| John Doe | A |
| Joe Smith | A |
| James Brown | B |

I am inputting the name of a person, and comparing them to the 'comps' dataframe highlighted above. I essentially want to create a confidence index when comparing the person input, and I want the confidence index to be subtracted by 10 if the person is in a different group. It would look something like this:

input_name = Jim Jones, input_group = A

| Name | Group | Confidence |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John Doe | A | 100 |
| Joe Smith | A | 100 |
| James Brown | B | 90 |

The code I currently have is

```
if comps.loc[comps['Group'] == input_group]:
    comps['Confidence'] = 100
else:
    comps['Confidence'] = 90
```

I'm getting the following traceback when I run this:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: so you just match the group? Because `input_name = Jim Jones` is no were near 100% match in the existing list of names you have

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
import pandas as pd

data = [
        ["John Doe", "A"],
        ["Joe Smith", "A"],
        ["James Brown", "B"]
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Name","Group"])
print(df)

print()

data = [
        ["John Doe", "A",100],
        ["Joe Smith", "A",100],
        ["James Brown", "C",100]
]

comps = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Name","Group","Confidence"])
print(comps)

print()

for index, (name1,group1,confidence)  in comps.iterrows():

    for index, (name2,group2) in df.iterrows():

        if((name2 == name1) and (group1 == group2)):
            comps.loc[comps.Name == name1,'Confidence'] = 100

        if((name2 == name1) and (group1 != group2)):
            comps.loc[comps.Name == name1,'Confidence'] = int(comps.loc[comps.Name == name1,'Confidence']) - 10

print(comps)
```

[image]